# DataTables search on multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering

I'm trying to search my table on multiple columns at the same time. 
Example

```
----------------------------
|  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |
----------------------------
|  abcd  |  efgh  |   12   |
|  bcde  |  efgh  |   34   |
|  cdef  |  efgh  |   56   |
----------------------------
```

I want to search "cd" in Col1 and "34" in Col3, so that the result would be

```
----------------------------
|  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |
----------------------------
|  bcde  |  efgh  |   34   |
----------------------------
```

I've added some input fields in my table's `thead` and when my custom event is triggered, Here is what I came up with:

```
$('#datatable_ajax thead').on( 'doneTyping', '.search-on-type', function(e){
    if ( $(this).val() ) {
        var colX = [];
        var values = [];
        $('#datatable_ajax thead .search-on-type').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "")
                return;
            var visIdx = $(this).closest('th').index();
            var idx = dTable.column.index( 'fromVisible', visIdx );
            colX.push(idx);
            values.push($(this).val());
        });
        if( colX.length == 3){
            dTable.clearPipeline().columns( colX[0] ).search( values[0] ).columns( colX[1] ).search( values[1] ).columns( colX[2] ).search( values[2] ).draw();
        } else if ( colX.length == 2){
            dTable.clearPipeline().columns( colX[0] ).search( values[0] ).columns( colX[1] ).search( values[1] ).draw();
        } else {
            dTable.clearPipeline().columns( colX[0] ).search( values[0] ).draw();
        }
    }
});
```

this code is working as expected.

But as you can see, the if-elseif-else is quite a bad solution, since I could have more than 3 fields which I want to search together, but I don't want to manually add an `elseif` each time I add a new searchable column.

I tried to find a better solution but I only found solutions for searching multiple columns with the same value, which is not what I need.

I noticed that `.columns()` accept an array as arguments, but `.search()` doesn't.. ( or at least, it does accept arrays, but they are transformed into comma separated string, which will be searched on the selected columns)

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do, is  fill up your `values` array with a regex pattern like `(.*?)` (that matches anything) for all columns for which no search filter has been defined.

This would allow you to reduce your if-elseif-else to a single statement :

```
$('#datatable_ajax thead').on( 'doneTyping', '.search-on-type', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        var colX = [], values = [], filter;

        $('#datatable_ajax thead .search-on-type').each(function() {
            filter = $(this).val();
            if(filter == "") {
                values.push("(.*?)"); // Regex that matches anything
            } else {
                values.push(filter);
            }
            colX.push(dTable.column.index( 'fromVisible', $(this).closest('th').index() ));
        });

        dTable.clearPipeline().columns( colX[0] ).search( values[0], true, false )
                              .columns( colX[1] ).search( values[1], true, false )
                              .columns( colX[2] ).search( values[2], true, false )
                              .draw();
    }
});
```